# Differences between an applications compile to run on Java 6 but running on the Java 8 JVM and the same App Compile on Java 8

Tags: java

We have an issue with an Application that used to work fine on Java 6 and now its having problem since it was recompiled using Java 8 and is run on the Java 8 JVM. What I was wondering is the following

App123 Compiled using Java 6 Running on the Java 8 JVM

vs

App123 Compiled using Java 8 Running on the Java 8 JVM ( current setup )

Would there be any difference in the Application/JVM behavior running on the Java 8 JVM based on how it was compiled ?

```
// printMessage called like this from UMSWorker Thread.
// PrintSystem.getInstance().printMessage(message);

//PrintSystem Class
public void printMessage(Object message) throws Exception
{
if (!initialized)
   throw new Exception("DEBUG: Print System not initialized!");
try 
{
synchronized(this)
{
 printList.add(message); // LinkedList 
 this.notify();
}
LogManager.traceMessage(this,"DEBUG: PrintSystem.PrintMessage()", 
 "printList Size : " + printList.size());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
 LogManager.traceMessage(this,"DEBUG: PrintSystem.PrintMessage() ", 
 "Exception : " + e);
}
}

public void run()  
{
Object message = null;
while (true)
{
 try
 {
  synchronized(this)
  {
   this.wait(2500);
  } 
}
catch (Exception e) {} 

 while (!printList.isEmpty())
 {
   synchronized(this) 
   {
     message = printList.removeFirst();
   }
   int printed = printPLMMessage((PLMHeader) message);
   PLMHeader ackHeader = generatePrinterAck((PLMHeader) 
   message,printed);
   Communications.getInstance().ack(ackHeader);
 }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're experiencing when starting on JRE 8?

Comment: Its with the PrintSystem Thread not responding until the app is restart the problem is intermittent. The Thread uses a LinkedList and synchronization and that sees to be a problem now that the code has been compiled under Java 8 and run under Java 8. There also seems to be a problem with the java.util.logger not working when the problem occurs so nothing much useful in the logs.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here, but rather than using `wait` and `notify` and `synchronized` with a LinkedList, it would probably be better to use a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` and just have a thread poll it in a loop. Then you don't need manual synchronization.

Comment: Hi Ryan thanks yes I have tested a ConcurrentLinkedQueue works great in limited testing however I can't reproduce the problem on my system so the LinkedList works there as well. My question is why would this work ok in Java 6 but not java 8 its worked for years until the change to use Java 8.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the code was always wrong but worked in 6 accidentally. I don't know but I noticed that you do removeFirst in a synchronized block but not add. Could be an issue? You also don't sync when checking isEmpty.

Comment: Hi Ryan I updated the add its actually in the sync , the isEmpty is the only part that isn't. Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this is your actual problem, but in general, you want the `isEmpty` check and the `removeFirst` action to be atomic, ie in the same synchronized block, which they aren't now.

Comment: Thanks Ryan yes ideally the isEmpty should be in the same sync block but I don't see that causing the thread to fail or not respond and that is what seems to be happening. If the isEmpty returns and invalid response it should cause the thread to hang I wouldn't think.

Comment: It could if the pace at which messages are being added is greater than the pace at which they're being removed.

Comment: Also having synchronized(this) around both wait() and notify() doesn't seem right. Doesn't that mean it can never wake out of wait() and will always have to timeout?